# Iterating through dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of 3 lists, each containing 3 elements, and want to alter each element within each list separately, generating 9 new dictionaries as such:

```
d = {1:[a,b,c], 2:[e,f,g], 3:[h,i,j]}
d1 = {1:[a+k,b,c], 2:[e,f,g], 3:[h,i,j]}
d2 = {1:[a, b+k, c], 2:[e,f,g], 3:[h,i,j]}
...
d9 = {{1:[a,b,c], 2:[e,f,g], 3:[h,i,j+k]}
```

Is there a way this can be done without having to hardcode each dictionary separately? Further on down the code, I will need to refer to the sets of lists separately (i.e. I will input [a,b,c+k], [d,e,f], [g,h,i] into some function to get a solution), but I am happy for the data not to be in dictionary form so long as I can still refer to their sets later!

Comment: I'm not too clear on what you are trying to do. What are you starting with and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: Basically, I have three vectors stored in a dictionary, and I need to alter each individual coordinate in each vector separately.

Comment: Put d1-d9 in a list?

Comment: @wjandrea yup! but could I somehow avoid having to type out d1-d9? (its actually 42 dictionaries in the code so I'd really rather not do things manually). Looking for a way to iterate through my initial dictionary to generate d1-d9

Comment: @Plasmid Yes, use a list comprehension.

Comment: Can you provide your initial dictionary?

Comment: @wjandrea elaborate? :) I know what list comprehension is but am still fairly new to python!

Comment: @busybear my initial dictionary is basically d, but with floats in place of the letters. Its actually an object representing a vector, but I seem to be able to manipulate the elements as floats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate a number from 0 to 8 and generate dicts of lists using a dict comprehension that outputs list items with possibly `k` added based on the quotient and remainder of 3 of the number:

```
[{k: [a + ('k' if n // 3 + 1 == k and n % 3 == i else '') for i, a in enumerate(l)] for k, l in d.items()} for n in range(9)]
```

so that given:

```
d = {1:['a','b','c'], 2:['e','f','g'], 3:['h','i','j']}
```

this returns:

```
[{1: ['ak', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g'], 3: ['h', 'i', 'j']},
 {1: ['a', 'bk', 'c'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g'], 3: ['h', 'i', 'j']},
 {1: ['a', 'b', 'ck'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g'], 3: ['h', 'i', 'j']},
 {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['ek', 'f', 'g'], 3: ['h', 'i', 'j']},
 {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['e', 'fk', 'g'], 3: ['h', 'i', 'j']},
 {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'gk'], 3: ['h', 'i', 'j']},
 {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g'], 3: ['hk', 'i', 'j']},
 {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g'], 3: ['h', 'ik', 'j']},
 {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g'], 3: ['h', 'i', 'jk']}]
```